Turan's theorem bound when $r\nmid n$
I learned the Turan's theorem states that Among all the $n$ vertex graphs with no clique of size $r+1$, Turan graph has the maximum number of edges and it is quite easy to give the exact number of the Turan graph whenever $r|n$, which is $(1-\frac{1}{r})(\frac{n^2}{2})$. However, if $r\nmid n$, then why the bound is still $(1-\frac{1}{r})(\frac{n^2}{2})$?

It's not that value. For a graph with no clique of size $r+1$, the maximum number of edges is attained by partitioning the $n$ vertices into $r$ sets that are as equal as possible in size. For example, if $r=3$ and $n=7$, the sets have sizes $2,2,3$.

The edge count of the Turán graph may differ from $(1 - \frac1r)\frac{n^2}{2}$ by up to $\frac r8$. The first example at which these are too far from each other for rounding to fix it is the $r=8$, $n=12$ case, in which the Turán graph $K_{2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1}$ has $62$ edges, and $(1-\frac18)\frac{12^2}{2} = 63$.

Let $n=qr+s$, $0\le s\le r-1$. Then Turan graph $T_r(n)$ has $s$ parts of size $q+1$ and $r-s$ parts of size $q$.
\begin{align*}e(T_{r}(n))&=\frac{1}{2}\left(s(q+1)(n-q-1)+(r-s)q(n-q)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(rq(n-q)+s(n-2q-1))\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left((n-s)(n-\frac{n-s}{r})+s(n-2\frac{n-s}{r}-1)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(n^2-\frac{n^2-sn}{r}-sn+\frac{sn-s^2}{r}+sn-2\frac{sn-s^2}{r}-s\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(n^2-\frac{n^2-s^2}{r}-s\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{s(r-s)}{2r}
\end{align*}
